# How can external object's field searchable in Global search

Tags: service

I have analyzed it and also enable 'allow search' on external object and also enable 'allow search' on external data source.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is it. The service has to support it as well, have you talked the one who is responsible for the service that provides the data for the external objects? 
You can try to open the developer console the see what happens in the log it should call the service with some parameters.

Answer (score 0):

No further config changes are required. When you search for a value for the external object, press enter.
If you see no results in the top results page, navigate on the left to select the object for which you would like to see for the search results. Scroll through all the objects available and reach the External results, from there click on the external object you are expecting the result for. Once clicked on the external object name, on the result pane on right hand side, you will see the records.

[image: External results snapshot]